# Scrapy doesn't wait for second request to scrape data in subsequent link

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy that searches for info in a page, eventually this info is not available in the page, but it has a link that contains the data I want. So I want to make my scraper access this data in the subsequent link. I have came with a idea of how to do it, but couldn't make it work yet.

I'm trying to have scrapy make:
 - Make a new request to the subsequent link
 - Scrape the data
 - Return the data
 - With all the data the script continues the next procedures

The problem is that the previous code (that called the new Request) doesn't wait for that second request, and eventually runs into an error, because of missing that data.

Here is the code (it's simplified, to just reflect what I'm asking)

```
def parse_hearing_page(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    selector = XPATH_PATTERN[self.page]
    for p in response.xpath(selector):
        date = ' '.join(p.xpath('strong/text()').extract())
        text = paragraph.xpath('.//text()').extract()
        scraped_data = {
            'date': parse_date(date),
            'author': None,
            'content': text,
            'url': response.url,
        }

        if date not in text:
            subsequent_page = p.xpath('../ul/li/a/@href').get()
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, subsequent_page), meta=scraped_data, callback=self.parse_author)
        else:
            author = text.split('Authors')[1]         
            scraped_data['location'] = author
        if scraped_data['author'] is None:
            raise ValueError
        scraped_data['id'] = self.get_id_from_author(scraped_data['author'], scraped_data['url'])
        yield scraped_data   

def parse_author(self, response):
    selector = ('//div//article[@id="authors"]/text()')
    item = response.meta['item']
    author = response.xpath(selector)
    item['author'] = author
    yield item
```

In the pages where the data is not available upfront the code will raise an error, because it didn't wait for the second request to scrape the data for scraped_data['author'].

I believe this might be the standard behavior, however is there a way to block it? Or another way to deal with this type of issue?

Comment: have you tried putting it in a try/except block and calling an implicit sleep with `time.sleep()` then having the script continue running from where it stopped. However, this would be you would have to change the structure of your code considerably

Comment: You could scrape two different types of entities, authors and articles, and do post-processing later on those, without Scrapy.